# Unable to click tSPAN buttons with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have an issue clicking the Continue Button of a Page . I have tried so many options but still the button is not clicked .

I have tried some options like this but not working

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//button[@id="cont_to_ins"]/span[contains(.,"Continue Booking")]')));
element.click()
```

This is the HTML Code

```
<button wn-validation-dom="prepaidcards-details" class="orange-btn btn btn-sm bold ng-scope" ng-if="!areOtherAddOnsAfterPrepaidCardsIndexAvailableInAccordion()" id="cont_to_ins" ng-click="continueBooking()">
<span translate="Resources.AddOns.PrepaidCards.Button_ContinueBooking" class="ng-scope">Continue Booking</span> 
<i class="material-icons "></i></button>

<span translate="Resources.AddOns.PrepaidCards.Button_ContinueBooking" 
class="ng-scope">Continue Booking</span>
```

i expect that once i click on this button , the next page should be displayed

Comment: is button inside frame? is it working manually?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the button rather than the span in the button. `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath('//button[@id="cont_to_ins"]')));`. Also check the events association to the button and span. I believe the click event might be attached to the button.

Comment: Please always add information about symptoms. Do you get any exception? If yes, post it.

Comment: The error i got when i tired is : element not interactable (   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='cont_to_ins']")).click();

Comment: Is there anything else following? Like "Other element would recieve the click"? Please always post as much information as possible (just rename or blur confidentials). I'd like to see complete page source code, your complete method and complete exception. "element not interactible" has more different symptoms and ofc more causes. From selenium's point of view, some elements may not be interactible at all.